# How to create line breaks in knitr::kable() tables with format="html"?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to include content with line breaks in html tables produced by `knitr::kable()`. All works well with the default `format="markdown"` parameter:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = "No line break", b = "With line<br>break")
> knitr::kable(x)
```

```
|a             |b                  |
|:-------------|:------------------|
|No line break |With line<br>break |
```

The above correctly appears as a line break in the rendered `html` document.

But with `format="html"`--which I would prefer to use for other reasons--the `<br>` tag is converted to `&lt;br&gt;` and then renders in `html` as `<br>` rather than an actual line break. Is there anything I can do to make it behave as it does with the default `format="markdown"`?

```
> knitr::kable(x, format="html")
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> a </th>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> b </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> No line break </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> With line&lt;br&gt;break </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

So after being stuck on this for a long time, I discovered just after posting this that the solution is simply to add `escape=FALSE` to the example with `format="html"`.